# Compressing file by file in gz in linux terminal

Tags: linux

I have several files in one folder and I would like to compress 1 by 1

```
Folder: /files
file1 to file1.gz
file2 to file2.gz
Etc
```

And that with all the files that are in the folder: /file

Is it possible to compress only the files (and not the folder) at once?

Comment: why not `cd /files; gzip file*` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are in search of looping mechanism to perform a `GZIP`. Below single-line execution can be a simple method to do it without any scripting.

```
for file_name in /files/* ; do gzip $file_name ;done
```

However, in case if the same directory holds directories as well as files, it better to have some beautified script for continuous use as below;

```
for file_name in /files/* 
do 
    if [ -f $file_name ]; then
        gzip $file_name
    else
        echo "$file_name is a directory."
    fi
done
```

PS :-

> 1. `else` logic is purely optional and can be commented.
> 2. Try to keep this script outside of `/files` directory, else it would zip the shell script file as well.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!